# Is it problematic that Spring Data REST exposes entities via REST resources without using DTOs?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, domain-driven-design, spring-data-rest

In my limited experience, I've been told repeatedly that you should not pass around entities to the front end or via rest, but instead to use a DTO.

Doesn't Spring Data Rest do exactly this? I've looked briefly into projections, but those seem to just limit the data that is being returned, and still expecting an entity as a parameter to a post method to save to the database. Am I missing something here, or am I (and my coworkers) incorrect in that you should never pass around and entity?

Comment: You are right spring data rest is exposing entities to frontend, a big mistake.  I do not recomend it, use DTO. regards

Comment: @duardito — would you mind elaborating why this is a mistake, especially in the light of the answer I gave below? What benefit would using DTOs provide?

Comment: In case of JaxB annotation while creating context it goes inside Hibernate libraries and causes performance issue, on first call or everytime jaxb creates the context for that entity. I belive Jackson would face the same issue while object mapping.

Answer (score 71):

## tl;dr

No. DTOs are just one means to decouple the server side domain model from the representation exposed in HTTP resources. You can also use other means of decoupling, which is what Spring Data REST does.

## Details

Yes, Spring Data REST inspects the domain model you have on the server side to reason about the way the representations for the resources it exposes will look like. However it applies a couple of crucial concepts that mitigate the problems a naive exposure of domain objects would bring.

### Spring Data REST looks for aggregates and by default shapes the representations accordingly.

The fundamental problem with the naive "I throw my domain objects in front of Jackson" is that from the plain entity model, it's very hard to reason about reasonable representation boundaries. Especially entity models derived from database tables have the habit to connect virtually everything to everything. This stems from the fact that important domain concepts like aggregates are simply not present in most persistence technologies (read: especially in relational databases).

However, I'd argue that in this case the "Don't expose your domain model" is more acting on the symptoms of that than the core of the problem. If you design your domain model properly there's a huge overlap between what's beneficial in the domain model and what a good representation looks like to effectively drive that model through state changes. A couple of simple rules:

- For every relationship to another entity, ask yourself: couldn't this rather be an id reference. By using an object reference you pull a lot of semantics of the other side of the relationship into your entity. Getting this wrong usually leads entities referring to entities referring to entities, which is a problem on a deeper level. On the representation level this allows you to cut off data, cater consistency scopes etc.
- Avoid bi-directional relationships as they're notoriously hard to get right on the update side of things.

Spring Data REST does quite a few things to actually transfer those entity relationships into the proper mechanisms on the HTTP level: links in general and more importantly links to dedicated resources managing those relationships. It does so by inspecting the repositories declared for entities and basically replaces an otherwise necessary inlining of the related entity with a link to an association resource that allows you to manage that relationship explicitly.

That approach usually plays nicely with the consistency guarantees described by DDD aggregates on the HTTP level. `PUT` requests don't span multiple aggregates by default, which is a good thing as it implies a scope of consistency of the resource matching the concepts of your domain.

### There's no point in forcing users into DTOs if that DTO just duplicates the fields of the domain object.

You can introduce as many DTOs for your domain objects as you like. In most of the cases, the fields captured in the domain object will reflect into the representation in some way. I have yet to see the entity `Customer` containing a `firstname`, `lastname` and `emailAddress` property, and those being completely irrelevant in the representation.

The introduction of DTOs doesn't guarantee a decoupling by no means. I've seen way too many projects where they where introduced for cargo-culting reasons, simply duplicated all fields of the entity backing them and by that just caused additional effort because every new field had to be added to the DTOs as well. But hey, decoupling! Not. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

That said, there are of course situations where you'd want to slightly tweak the representation of those properties, especially if you use strongly typed value objects for e.g. an `EmailAddress` (good!) but still want to render this as a plain `String` in JSON. But by no means is that a problem: Spring Data REST uses Jackson under the covers which offers you a wide variety of means to tweak the representation — annotations, mixins to keep the annotations outside your domain types, custom serializers etc. So there is a mapping layer in between.

Not using DTOs by default is not a bad thing per se. Just imagine the outcry by users about the amount of boilerplate necessary if we required DTOs to be written for everything! A DTO is just *one* means to an end. If that end can be achieved in a different way (and it usually can), why insist on DTOs?

### Just don't use Spring Data REST where it doesn't fit your requirements.

Continuing on the customization efforts it's worth noticing that Spring Data REST exists to cover exactly the parts of the API, that just follow the basic REST API implementation patterns it implements. And that functionality is in place to give you more time to think about

1. How to shape your domain model
2. Which parts of your API are better expressed through hypermedia driven interactions.

Here's a slide from the talk I gave at SpringOne Platform 2016 that summarizes the situation.

[image: What makes up a REST API built with Spring Data REST]

*The complete slide deck can be found [here](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/advanced-spring-data-rest). There's also a [recording of the talk](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/spring-data-rest-springone2016) available on InfoQ.*

Spring Data REST exists for you to be able to focus on the underlined circles. By no means we think you can build a great really API solely by switching Spring Data REST on. We just want to reduce the amount of boilerplate for you to have more time to think about the interesting bits.

Just like Spring Data in general reduces the amount of boilerplate code to be written for standard persistence operations. Nobody would argue you can actually build a real world app from only CRUD operations. But taking the effort out of the boring bits, we allow you to think more intensively about the real domain challenges (and you should actually do that :)).

You can be very selective in overriding certain resources to completely take control of their behavior, including manually mapping the domain types to DTOs if you want. You can also place custom functionality next to what Spring Data REST provides and just hook the two together. Be selective about what you use.

### A sample

You can find a slightly advanced example of what I described in [Spring RESTBucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks), a Spring (Data REST) based implementation of the RESTBucks example in the RESTful Web Services book. It uses Spring Data REST to manage `Order` instances but tweaks its handling to introduce custom requirements and completely implement the payment part of the story manually.

Comment: Thanks. Also learned what is `Cargo Cult Programming` refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: ["The core functionality of Spring Data REST is to export resources for Spring Data repositories."](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.5.3/reference/html/#repository-resources) In that statement we must agree with your answer. If an API is fulfilled by data joined from another API, or from cache or data store Spring Data does not support, one needs to use Spring HATEOAS and a custom resource representation (i.e DTO layer). _"There's no point in forcing users into DTOs.."_ .. with caveat that change to the Entity model could breaks the API contract. Can SpringDR use DTO abstraction?

Comment: After reading this, I can imagine most of my previous projects I could use Spring Data Rest. Even if you don't like HAL specification, you can mostly cut some parts since the response structure is greatly customizable in SDR. Thanks for the extensive explanation!

Answer (score 13):

Spring Data REST enables a very fast way to prototype and create a REST API based on a database structure. We're talking about minutes vs days, when comparing with other programming technologies.

The price you pay for that, is that your REST API is tightly coupled to your database structure. Sometimes, that's a big problem. Sometimes it's not. It depends basically on the quality of your database design and your ability to change it to suit the API user needs.

In short, I consider Spring Data REST as a tool that can save you a lot of time under certain special circumstances. Not as a silver bullet that can be applied to any problem.

Answer (score 6):

We used to use DTOs including the fully traditional layering ( Database, DTO, Repository, Service, Controllers,...) for every entity in our projects. Hopping the DTOs will some day save our life :)

So for a simple `City` entity which has `id,name,country,state` we did as below:

1. `City` table with `id,name,county,....` columns
2. `CityDTO` with `id,name,county,....` properties ( exactly same as database)
3. `CityRepository` with a `findCity(id),....`
4. `CityService` with `findCity(id) { CityRepository.findCity(id) }`
5. `CityController` with `findCity(id) { ConvertToJson( CityService.findCity(id)) }`

Too many boilerplate codes just to expose a city information to client. As this is a simple entity no business is done at all along these layers, just the objects is passing by.
A change in `City` entity was starting from database and changed all layers. (For example adding a `location` property, well because at the end the `location` property should be exposed to user as `json`). Adding a  `findByNameAndCountryAllIgnoringCase` method needs all layers be changed changed ( Each layer needs to have new method).

Considering Spring Data Rest ( `of course with Spring Data`) this is beyond simple!

```
public interface CityRepository extends CRUDRepository<City, Long> {
   City findByNameAndCountryAllIgnoringCase(String name, String country);
}
```

The `city` entity is exposed to client with minimum code and still you have control on how the city is exposed. `Validation`, `Security`, `Object Mapping` ... is all there. So you can tweak every thing.

For example, if I want to keep client unaware on `city` entity property name  change (layer separation), well I can use custom Object mapper mentioned https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.custom-jackson-deserialization

**To summarize**

We use the Spring Data Rest as much as possible, in complicated use cases we still can go for traditional layering and let the `Service` and `Controller` do some business.

Answer (score 0):

A client/server release is going to publish at least two artifacts.  This already decouples client from server.  When the server's API is changed, applications do not immediately change.  Even if the applications are consuming the JSON directly, they continue to consume the legacy API.

So, the decoupling is already there.  The important thing is to think about the various ways a server's API is likely to evolve after it is released.

I primarily work with projects which use DTOs and numerous rigid layers of boilerplate between the server's SQL and the consuming application.  Rigid coupling is just as likely in these applications.  Often, changing anything in the DB schema requires us to implement a new set of endpoints.  Then, we support both sets of endpoints along with the accompanying boilerplate in each layer (Client, DTO, POJO, DTO <-> POJO conversions, Controller, Service, Repository, DAO, JDBC <-> POJO conversion, and SQL).

I'll admit that there is a cost to dynamic code (like spring-data-rest) when doing anything not supported by the framework.  For example, our servers need to support a lot of batch insert/update operations.  If we only need that custom behavior in a single case, it's certainly easier to implement it without spring-data-rest.  In fact, it may be too easy.  Those single cases tend to multiply.  As the number of DTOs and accompanying code grows, the inconsistencies eventually become extremely burdensome to maintain.  In some non-dynamic server implementations, we have hundreds of DTOs and POJOs that are likely no longer used by anything.  But, we are forced to continue supporting them as their number grows each month.

With spring-data-rest, we pay the cost of customization early.  With our multi-layer hard-coded implementations, we pay it later.  Which one is preferred depends on a lot of factors (including the team's knowledge and the expected lifetime of the project).  Both types of project can collapse under their own weight.  But, over time, I've become more comfortable with implementations (like spring-data-rest without DTOs) that are more dynamic.  This is especially true when the project lacks good specifications.  Over time, such a project can easily drown in the inconsistencies buried within its sea of boilerplate.

Answer (score -1):

From the Spring documentation I don't see Spring data REST exposes entities, you are the one doing it.
Spring Data projects intend to ease the process of accessing different data sources, but you are the one deciding which layer to expose on Spring Data Rest.

Reorganizing your project will help to solve your issue.

Every @Repository that you create with Spring data represents more a DAO in the sense of design than a Repository. Each one is tightly coupled with a particular Data source you want to reach out to. Say JPA, Mongo, Redis, Cassandra,...
Those layers are meant to return entity representations or projections.

However if you check out the Repository pattern from a design perspective you should have a higher layer of abstraction from those specific DAOs where your app use those DAOs to get info from as many different sources it needs, and builds business specific objects for your app (Those might looks more like your DTOs).
That is probably the layer you want to expose on your Spring Data Rest.

NOTE: I see an answer recommending to return Entity instances only because they have the same properties as the DTO. This is normally a bad practice and in particular is a bad idea in Spring and many other frameworks because they do not return your actual classes, they return proxy wrappers so that they can work some magic like lazy loading of values and the likes.