# Spring Data Rest: 500 error when 4xx expected

Tags: spring-data-rest

Given the following entities, when I "post" a new entity of "TrainerProfile" and miss some of the @NotNull parameters in "Location", I get a 500 together with a stack trace packed into the JSON instead of a 400 and useful information on what went wrong.

```
@Entity
public class TrainerProfile {
    ...

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Location location;

}

@Entity
public class Location {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String zipcode;

    @NotNull
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    private String country;

}
```

When I post this data to the API

```
{
  ...
  "location": {
    "zipcode": "10000"
  }
}
```

I see the following logs:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [training.edit.provider.model.Location] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=city, rootBeanClass=class training.edit.provider.model.Location, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=country, rootBeanClass=class training.edit.provider.model.Location, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
```

But the REST client sees this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 500
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 09:33:16 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{"timestamp":"2020-06-16T09:33:16.605+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction","trace":"org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:543)\n...
```

The text is way longer but I spare you the rest.

I configured validation like this:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class RestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    private final @NonNull Validator validator;

    private final @NonNull UriToIdConverter converter;

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        RepositoryRestConfigurer.super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
        conversionService.addConverter(converter);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
       validatingListener.addValidator("afterCreate", validator);
       validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", validator);
       validatingListener.addValidator("afterSave", validator);
       validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", validator);
    }

}
```

How can I get a proper error message in this case? When I post something that doesn't work for "TrainerProfile" then I get a proper message and error code, but not for the nested object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Intermediate Solution

Each Spring Data REST request issue a transaction. The outter exception `RollbackException` gives you a `500` response, even though this exception actually comes from nested validation failure `ConstraintViolationException`. An working but not nice solution should be have a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` to extract the nested exception, as the [auth0 example](https://auth0.com/blog/spring-data-rest-tutorial-developing-rest-apis-with-ease/). The code is [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/spring-data-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/auth0/ads/RestExceptionHandler.java).

## Suggestion

> Just don't use Spring Data REST where it doesn't fit your requirements.

as said by Spring Data REST leader Oliver Drotbohm in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874746/is-it-problematic-that-spring-data-rest-exposes-entities-via-rest-resources-with/38876046#38876046).

A RESTful API should work for *aggregate*. *Aggregate* is a DDD concept. Aggregate doesn't work well with relational database. Try No-SQL database such as Mongo DB. The starting point to learn DDD is [Oliver's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdZqeAAIHzc&t=2323s).