# spring boot hibernate, how to avoid returning all the child objects?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have the following entities:

Customer, Account, Currency.

Customers can have many (set of) accounts, accounts have a currency.
Thus in the DB, the accounts table has a `customer_id`, and also a `currency_id` FK.

When we read a customer record, hibernate always also reads both accounts table and currency table, even if we specify `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`.

1. How can we get hibernate, in specific circumstances, to only query customers, and not their accounts?
2. How can we get account to only return the `currency_id`, and not the whole currency record?  we keep an in memory map of the currency table, for speed, its really on also in the DB for reporting.

customer entity:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "customer_seq", sequenceName = "customer_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "customer_seq")
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Account> accounts;
}
```

Strangely, for the Account object, we had to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` to avoid the error:

> No serializer found for class
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor

but didn't have to add it for the other lazy loaded relationships.

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Account  {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "account_seq", sequenceName = "account_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "account_seq")
    private Long id;

    BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(0);

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore  // this is required to avoid recursion when returning customer json, which was unexpected because it should be lazy.
    Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    Currency currency;

    }
```

This is how we are querying the customer:

```
RestController
class CustomerController {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class);

    private final CustomerRepository repository;

    CustomerController(CustomerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getCustomer")
    public Customer getCustomer(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return this.repository.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

This is the resultant http response:

```
{
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null,
    "version": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "email": "customer1@test.com",
    "password": "haha123",
    "phone": null,
    "accounts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "balance": 100.00,
            "currency": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "version": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "iso": "GBP",
                "name": "Pound Sterling",
                "prefix": "£",
                "suffix": "",
                "decimalPlaces": 2,
                "visible": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "dob": null
}
```

I assume I would need to provide two different endpoints, or a parameter, and then somehow switch in the controller to pull back either only the customer, or the customer with accounts. Would I need to hardcode explicit SQL in custom service methods for this, or does spring/hibernate have something out of the box?

Also, when I query for accounts, I would ideally want it to return something like this:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "balance": 100.00,
            "currencyId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "balance": 100.00,
            "currency": {
                "createdAt": null,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "version": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "iso": "GBP",
                "name": "Pound Sterling",
                "prefix": "£",
                "suffix": "",
                "decimalPlaces": 2,
                "visible": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add `@JsonIgnore` annotation on property `private Set<Account> accounts` will remove that object from response.

When spring return response it will try to convert entity object into JSON object. So it will convert parent its child in to JSON so it will fetch all the child object and convert into JSON. It will also keep hibernate session open until the response send.

You should not expose Entity object directy in response. Instead convert them to DTO/VO object and return from response. Checkout [Adding fields to an object returned by Spring Data Rest endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921071/adding-fields-to-an-object-returned-by-spring-data-rest-endpoint/74037643#74037643)

The VO/DTO will give you total control what you want to expose in API and also reduce overhead of hibernate.

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed that the JsonIgnore would just hide it from the frontend, not stop hibernate from doing additional queries. The issue is that in some cases i want to return customer with accounts, sometimes, without. I assume if I hard code the JsonIgnore on the Account field, I have to manually query accounts and append them to the customer object in the controller or service layer, but unfortunately the JsonIngore will still block it from being converted to JSon.  Using DTOs is ok, but when you have 400+ tables and need to get it running quickly, no time for so much boiler plate code

Comment: For condition you should use `@JsonInclude` with `valueFilter` or `contentFilter` that will give you control when to return data and when not. But you should check enable hibernate log and check when those accounts are fetched. If its before your controller dispatch then you must have code which access that property. If not then jackson will do while converting object to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the lazy fetch type is specified for associated entities, the entire `Customer` object is returned from the endpoint, leading to the initialization of lazy-loaded fields during serialization.

You can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html), to retrieve only needed properties, since Spring Data allows modeling dedicated return types, to more selectively retrieve partial views of the managed aggregates.

For each response type, it's preferable to provide a separate endpoint. For example, to provide an endpoint for returning a customer with accounts, you can do the following.

First, declare an interface projection that exposes accessor methods for the properties to be read.

```java
public interface CustomerWithAccountsProjection {
  String getFirstName();

  String getLasName();

  String getEmail();

  Set<AccountProjection> getAccounts();

  interface AccountProjection {
    Long getId();

    BigDecimal getBalance();

    CurrencyProjection getCurrency();
  }

  interface CurrencyProjection {
    Long getId();
  }
}
```

> The important bit here is that the properties defined here exactly
> match properties in the aggregate root.

Then declare a query method in the repository.

```java
interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    Optional<CustomerWithAccountsProjection> findCustomerWithAccountsById(Long id);
}
```

> The query execution engine creates proxy instances of that interface
> at runtime for each element returned and forwards calls to the exposed
> methods to the target object.

That's it. For other use cases, just declare a new interface and method in the repository.

With this approach, there's no need to pollute entity models with serialization-related annotations such as `@JsonIgnore`. Additionally, lazy-loaded associations would not be fetched unless declared in a projection.

If you need a more flexible API, I suggest [GraphQL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/).

Answer (score 1):

Basically the issue is that you use entities as Dto you should think to separe your conscern even if your api schema and db schema are close duplicate class is always better. Your case is a perfect exemple use :
public record AccountDto(Long id ,BigDecimal balance,Currency currency) {} as return of your controller and use a mapper that map from account to accountDto ignoring your custommer field is easy and mapstruct could do the job with few code.

By the way your JSONIgnore is not handle because the object process by jackson at deserialisation is not exactly an instance of your entity but a proxy provide by hibernate to handle @OneToMany subrequest when Jackson that why jackson didn't see the annotation.